# Is there a way to wrap the toolbar buttons to the next row in TinyMCE if the width of the editor is too small?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE in advanced theme. Today I must specify in advance the buttons in each toolbar row: theme_advanced_buttons1, theme_advanced_buttons2 and theme_advanced_buttons3.

Is there a way to just specify a single list of buttons and let the buttons wrap to the next row if the width of the editor is too small to contain them all in a single line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately, this is not possible (using Tinymce3).
For Tinymce4, this is another issue.

Comment: The question dates back to 2012 and with tinymce3 this is not possible. Tinymce4 makes it work!

Comment: Outdated answer. Now TinyMCE 4 Supports this.

Comment: @Thariama Why not update the answer to reflect both version 3 and 4. Mention that version 3 is not possible, version 4 is possible. I could remove the down vote, and even up vote.

Comment: @Basil: I do not know how many tinymce tickets i have answered during the last years, but i guess there are several hundret. I do not have the time to update every one of those answers. I hope you do understand that.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: i just had a closer look here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/tinymce/topusers - i have answered 1350 tinymce questions so far (most of them tinymce3)  :)

Answer (score 20):

It doesn't do it by itself, but in tinyMCE 4.X, you can add multiple toolbars like below

```
tinymce.init({
        selector: ".tinymce-textarea",
        theme: "modern",
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
            "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen textcolor emoticons",
            "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste jbimages"//moxiemanager
        ],
        file_browser_callback: false,
        toolbar1: " bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist | outdent indent | link image media preview ",
        toolbar2: "forecolor backcolor emoticons | jbimages ",
        relative_urls : false

    });
```

Comment: In tinymce 4.3 i need to use an array: tinymce.init({ toolbar: [
                'bold italic',
                'underline styleselect'
            ] })

Answer (score 15):

I'm surprised this wasn't an answer, but I just used:

```
.mce-btn-group .mce-btn {
    float: left;
}
```

I only have one toolbar, and on smaller screens it just wraps as needed.

Comment: Searched far and wide for this! Thanks! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the other way around: [TinyMCE: How to display all toolbars on a single row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394608/tinymce-how-to-display-all-toolbars-on-a-single-row)

It will not wrap each button on its own, but I think you can do better that way.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible when using inline mode.

Answer (score -1):

Works with TinyMCE 3.x

```
.mceToolbar td {float: left;}
```