# TinyMCE: How to display all toolbars on a single row?

Tags: javascript, css, editor, tinymce

This question is basically reverse of [Is there a way to wrap the toolbar buttons to the next row in TinyMCE if the width of the editor is too small?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889735/is-there-a-way-to-wrap-the-toolbar-buttons-to-the-next-row-in-tinymce-if-the-wid)

I have a TinyMCE editor where I have buttons specified via theme_advanced_buttons1, theme_advanced_buttons2 and theme_advanced_buttons3. Each toolbar row is designed to be pretty short to make sure that the layout will not overflow horizontally.

**Is there a way to get toolbars to reposition on a single line if they can all fit?** (E.g. visitor has a wide-screen display and the browser window is maximized.)

I'm thinking it could be possible via CSS by settings `display:block` and `float:left` to toolbar rows (the `tr` elements). Perhaps add `clear: left` to some (which?) following element to prevent overflowing to editor area. However, this seems like an ugly hack. I'm hoping you can come up with something better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each line of buttons is wrapped in a table so `theme_advanced_buttons1` is inside a table, `theme_advanced_buttons2` is inside another table and `theme_advanced_buttons3` is inside another one, so to make them inline you can use

```
.wp_themeSkin table.mceToolbar {
  margin: 0 6px 2px; // this is by default
  display: inline-table; // this is extra I've added to keep them in single line
}
```

Below is a screenshot of `display: inline-table;` in full screen mode of the editor, all three lines of buttons are in one line, side by side

[image]

Comment: Thanks but you know So is a place that teaches us something new everyday, at least i learn from it always and learning is not over until you die. All the best :-)

Comment: Using `display: inline-table` or `display: inline-block` seems to work for getting the toolbars on the first line. However, at least with Firefox and Chrome, the wrapping does not work back to multiline display if window is too narrow (or made narrow while the TinyMCE editor is visible). Does it work for you? I think the issue caused by the fact that toolbar `table` elements follow each other without any whitespace in between and as such, the browser does not see a line break opportunity between toolbar parts.

Comment: It works but overflows the wrapper div, brings all the tables in a single line.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the number of buttons enabled, setting table.mceToolbar to **display inline-table** can push the editor's width to be too wide.

Instead float each table left so it breaks when the maximum allowable width is reached.

```
 table.mceToolbar {margin-left:3px; float:left}
```

Answer (score 1):

This won't work using css only because the different rows have an own table element.
What you can do is to check before tinymce initialization how wide the users screen is.
Depending on this value you may set the `theme_advanced_buttons1` and `theme_advanced_buttons2` etc...

Example:

```
var width = screen.width;

tinyMCE.init({
mode: 'exact',
    ....

    theme_advanced_buttons1 : width < 1024 ? "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter" : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : width < 1024 ? "justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect" : "",
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this Jquery line at your javascript code:

```
$('[id^=tinyelement_toolbar]').css('display','inline-table')
```