# How to make TinyMCE Responsive

Tags: tinymce, responsive-design

I am making a Responsive site using the foundation framework and TinyMCE breaks the format when the page is scaled down(it's not responsive). How do I make TinyMCE responsive?

Comment: I did some research and I think it can be done with <iframe> but from there I cant seem to figure it out

Comment: what do you mean with "responsive"?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The TinyMCE editor can be made responsive by using css media queries. Simply add css rules that set the width property of `table.mceLayout` and the tinyMCE textareas. You will need to enforce these css rules using `!important` because they would otherwise be overwritten.

E.g., I use css similar to this:

```css
/* on mobile browsers, I set a width of 100% */
table.mceLayout, textarea.tinyMCE {
    width: 100% !important;
}

/* on large screens, I use a different layout, so 600px are sufficient */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    table.mceLayout, textarea.richEditor {
       width: 600px !important;
    }
}
```

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/johannesjh/384uf/

Note: You may wish to use different media queries or css classes to make use to the "foundation framework"'s responsive grid.

Comment: Thank you for the CSS declarations. That saved me so much time. Do you know if there's a way to get the toolbars to wrap on smaller screens?

Comment: Not sure about this one. But relevant links may include: 
http://blog.soundtraining.net/2008/06/tinymce-editor-width-in-joomla.html
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889735/is-there-a-way-to-wrap-the-toolbar-buttons-to-the-next-row-in-tinymce-if-the-wid
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394608/tinymce-how-to-display-all-toolbars-on-a-single-row

Answer (score 12):

There is a way to get the toolbars to wrap on smaller screens.

```
/* make the toolbar wrap */
.mceToolbar td {
    display:table-row;
    float: left;
}
.mceToolbar td:nth-of-type(11){
    clear: left;
}
```

I made a fork of the fiddle that Johannes posted that includes the above rules:

http://jsfiddle.net/joshfeck/gMVSE/

Comment: thank you i'm going to use like this `.mceToolbar > tbody > tr > td {
    display:table-row;
    float: left;
}`

Comment: this is very useful. I had to change the width to 100% for screen bigger than 600px.

Comment: In mi case with Tinymce 4 `.mce-toolbar .mce-btn{ display:table-row; float: left; }`

Answer (score 1):

I'm using version 4 of TinyMCE, there is a plugin named autoresize. It makes the editor responsive.

Comment: How do you get it to work?  I added `plugins: "autoresize"` to my init argument but the horizontal scrollbar still shows up on a smaller window.  Using tinymce-4.3.2

Comment: The autoresize plugin doesn't make the editor responsive. From the manual: "This plugin automatically resizes the editor to the content inside it. It is typically used to prevent the editor from expanding infinitely as a user types into the editable area. For example, by giving the autoresize_max_height option a value the editor will stop resizing when the set value is reached."

Answer (score 1):

Making the toolbar responsive for the latest version of TinyMCE:

```
.tox-toolbar {
    flex-wrap: nowrap !important;
    overflow-x: auto !important;
}
.tox-toolbar__group {
    flex-wrap: nowrap !important;
}
```

This adds a horizontal scrollbar to the toolbar on mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

TinyMCE 5.1 was released with a new mobile responsive design.

To ensure it functions as intended, you need to add the following code to the head of your pages that are using TinyMCE.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

More information here: https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/the-future-of-work-is-mobile-and-tiny-is-ready-for-it

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I use on a site to make the editor resize and the toolbars moves with the size of the page :

```
.mceEditor table {
max-width:none; /* Bug in computation of fullscreen */
}

.mceEditor table.mceLayout {
width:100% !important;
height:auto !important;
} 

table.mceToolbar { float:left; }
body .mceToolbar div {
white-space:normal;
}
```

Using small toolbar, they are properly layed out as the editor width changes.
"theme_advanced_resizing" should be set to "false". Also, more work is needed to make it work with fullscreen.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Width and height from the TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG.
then apply your styling normally.

Answer (score 0):

i am using this in the CSS:

```
div.tox.tox-tinymce {
  width: 200px !important;
}
```

I use `!important` because tinymce using inline styling for that div, use `@media` if necessary.

[a cropped screenshot from firefox inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRSFq.png)