# How to edit width of TinyMCE editor in Rails App based on screen width

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, tinymce

I'm trying to edit the width of the TinyMCE editor in a Rails 5 App based on the size of the screen.

I tried initially using the code below, which seems to work sometimes when you refresh the page manually, but if you navigate to another page of my site that has a TinyMCE editor on it without clicking the refresh button, the settings do not take effect.

```
if (screen.width < 700) {
    tinymce.init({
      selector: '.tinymce',  // change this value according to your HTML
      plugins: ['image', 'link', 'codesample', 'preview'],
      toolbar: 'styleselect | bold italic | undo redo | link image | codesample | preview',
      branding: false,
      width: 250,
      height: 250
    });
} else {
    tinymce.init({
      selector: '.tinymce',  // change this value according to your HTML
      plugins: ['image', 'link', 'codesample', 'preview'],
      toolbar: 'styleselect | bold italic | undo redo | link image | codesample | preview',
      branding: false,
      width: 700,
      height: 250
    });
}
```

I tried wrapping the above code in the following function based on some suggestions on StackOverflow regarding turbolinks, but this caused the settings to not take effect at all:

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
})
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Just trying to figure out the best method to edit the width of TinyMCE based on screen size (or window size would work too).

Note: I also tried the solution here and didn't have any luck: [How to make TinyMCE Responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991548/how-to-make-tinymce-responsive)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
tinymce.init({
      selector: '.tinymce',  // change this value according to your HTML
      plugins: ['image', 'link', 'codesample', 'preview'],
      toolbar: 'styleselect | bold italic | undo redo | link image | codesample | preview',
      branding: false,
      width: (screen.width < 700) ? 250 : 700,
      height: 250
    });
```

Comment: This works when I refresh the page also, but does not work on the initial page load.